# Am I right using "as" for equality and "than" to point out differences?

Tags: word-choice, comparatives

I would like to know whether I am right when I use "as" meaning: *similar, equal or equivalent*, and the comparative, "than", to point out a *difference* between the nouns.

Comment: Generally, yes. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: I agree, an example would be good.

Comment: Thanks, your answers make me understand the right way to use "as" and "than" better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct and is described in formal detail in the book:

[How English Works: A Grammar Practice Book With Answers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0194314561)

On page 88 it describes the usage of as:

> We use **as ... as** to say that people or things are **equal** in some way.

On page 87 it says:

> **Than** is used **after comparatives**.

On page 83 it says:
We use **comparatives** to compare **one** person, thing, action or group with **another** person, thing, etc...

*Homework:*

As a homework question, how is a comparative different than a superlative :)?

Also, you might benefit from doing the following quiz, specifically on this issue:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/apps/ifl/worldservice/quiznet/quizengine?ContentType=text/html;quiz=1128_as_as

In fact, in your spare time, the whole site has excellent quizzes in general:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/quizzes/quiznet/